# Mattermost still reading the standard config

Tags: mattermost

I installed mattermost and adapted the config.json, but I still can't start the service

```
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07 12:21:58.972 +01:00","level":"error","msg":"Failed to ping DB","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:259","error":"pq: password authentication failed for user \"mmuser\"","retrying in seconds":10}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07 12:22:08.973 +01:00","level":"info","msg":"Pinging SQL","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:251","database":"master","dataSource":"postgres://%2A%2A%2A%2A:%2A%2A%2A%2A@localhost/mattermost_test?binary_parameters=yes&connect_timeout=10&sslmode=disable"}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07 12:22:08.985 +01:00","level":"error","msg":"Failed to ping DB","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:259","error":"pq: password authentication failed for user \"mmuser\"","retrying in seconds":10}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07 12:22:18.986 +01:00","level":"info","msg":"Pinging SQL","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:251","database":"master","dataSource":"postgres://%2A%2A%2A%2A:%2A%2A%2A%2A@localhost/mattermost_test?binary_parameters=yes&connect_timeout=10&sslmode=disable"}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07 12:22:18.999 +01:00","level":"error","msg":"failed to initialize platform: cannot create store: error setting up connections: pq: password authentication failed for user \"mmuser\"","caller":"commands/server.go:76"}
```

I already changed the "localhost" or the "mattermost_test" entry,... part. I couldn't find the "database" settings in the config, I thought that's defined via the DataSource entry. Where is mattermost reading this? As I understood it I only had to adapt the config.json. Are there other config files?

Comment: Same problem here. No idea what is happening here.